# Derivative of $f(x) := \min(H(a+x),H(b-x))$ in the sense of distributions (Schwarz)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers and consider the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x) := \min(H(a+x),H(b-x)),$$ where $H:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is the Heaviside function defined by
$$
H(u) = \begin{cases}0,&\mbox{ if }u \le 0,\\
1,&\mbox{ if }u>0.
\end{cases}
$$

> **Question.** *In the sense of distributions, what is the derivative of $f$ ?*

I know that $H$ is locally-integrable and its derivative is the well-known *Dirac distribution* $\delta$. However, I'm very new to the theory of distributions, and I don't quite know how to go about the above problem.

Comment: This function is $0$ when $x<-a$ and $x>b$. Otherwise it is 0. You know derivative of heaviside function is dirac delta. So the derivative is $\delta(x+a)-\delta(x-b)$. Just think about the graph of this function it behaves like heaviside at $x=-a$ and behaves like "minus" heaviside  at $x=b$.

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç indeed, thank you very much. Feel free to copy-paste your comment as an anwser and I'll happily upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

$$ f^{\prime}(x)~=~H(a+b) [\delta(x+a)-\delta(x-b)] .$$